# how to write a file on iPhone using qt5.2

Tags: ios, qt, qt5

I'm writing an app on the iPhone using Qt5.2. When the app is running I'd like to
save some information from the user input to a file so the next time the user start the app he will have the save information.

I tried to do this:

```
QString cur_dir = QDir::currentPath();
QString init_file = cur_dir+"/init.xml";

QSettings settings( init_file, QSettings::IniFormat );
settings.setValue("General/SavedVariable", sel_label->text() );
```

but the file was not created when i verify doing this:

```
if( !QFileInfo( init_file ).exists() )
    std::cout << "FILE DOES NOT EXISTS " << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "FILE EXISTS " << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. You can not save a file in the Bundle directory. You have to
save in the Documents directory.
 Below is the code I used to do that:

```
{
      QString cur_dir = QDir::currentPath();

      int found = cur_dir.lastIndexOf( "/" );

      QString leftSide = cur_dir.left(found+1);
      leftSide += "Documents";

      init_file = leftSide+"/init.xml";

      if( !QFileInfo( init_file ).exists() )
         writeConfig();
      else
         readConfig();
}

void
writeConfig( void )
{
    QSettings settings( init_file, QSettings::IniFormat );
    settings.setValue("General/SavedVariable", sel_label->text() );
}

void
readConfig( void )
{
    QSettings settings( init_file, QSettings::IniFormat );
    QString save_var = settings.value( "General/SavedVariable" ).toString();
    sel_label->setText( save_var );
}
```

This is one way. You could also add to your project a objective C file .mm to your
qt project and get the Documents path directly.

```
NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                           NSUserDomainMask,
                                                           YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually in IOS you can't save your files in current directory(not bad to check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)). I used [QStandardPaths](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html) class and wrote this code to make it cross-platform:

```
QString path = QStandardPaths::standardLocations( QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation ).value(0);

QDir myDir(path);
if (!myDir.exists()) {
    myDir.mkpath(path);
}
QDir::setCurrent(path);
```

Now, it's okay to make your files or directories here in current dir.

Answer (score 0):

Applications are permitted/expected to write to the iOS Documents directory. Data written here is persistent and will be backed up during the iTunes backup process.

```
#include <QStandardPaths>

QFile myfile(QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::HomeLocation).append("/Documents/mystuff.txt"));
myfile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
```